# How to avoid eval() for parsing complex math strings (without php code) retrieved from MySQL field?

Tags: php, eval

The problem:

We're running a PHP-based site that calculates 'indicators' for our work. Each indicator has an unique way to be calculated, and, because they are revised frequently, so are the way they're calculated.

While today we get...

'total sorted'/'time spent' = 'sorted/second' (should be >= 1254)

Tomorrow it may change to...

'total sorted'/'highest sorted per hour' = 'hours needed' (should be <= 'time spent')

Now, for the way we do it:

First of all, we already know how eval() can be dangerous. So, let's explain what was done to avoid malicous code:

We have:

1. click-able buttons to add expressions in our code, like '(', ')', '+', '-', '*', '/'
2. click-able -specific index variables, like 'total sent', 'highest sent', 'lowest sent', 'start time', 'end time'
3. a 'number only' field with a 'click to add' button. It checks if
   this field has only a number (be it integer or float)
4. a read-only input field where those data is stored after each button is clicked
5. Obviously, a submit button

This will give us a custom math expression e.g: ('total sent'/('end time' - 'start time'))*27

That will be stored on MySQL on a 'indicators' table.

What we do now:

1. We run a SQL Query to retrieve that indicator
2. We replace each variable with a php variable: that example, we
   would get $expression='($totalSent/($endTime-$startTime))*27'
3. After all that, we use eval($expression)

FINALLY, what we WANT: since eval() is evil(), both for malicious code AND performance stuff, and the result will be used in graphs, tables and stuff, we need to know if there's a better way (without tons of code, of course) to turn the entered math expression into a valid equation.

Comment: eval is about as evil as hammer is for driving a screw in the wall; like a hammer, eval can be used for fun and profit, but, as the hammer, it's also easy to abuse. Do you have a specific security or performance problem or is this working as it should? If it works, then don't fix it...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker That's what I think, when we focus on security issues. The way we coded it, it has almost no chance to get malicious code - after all, no actual php code is stored on my database. What concerns me is performance stuff. More people will access the site soon.

Comment: You probably want to measure the performance before acting, it's impact *may* be smaller than you think....

Comment: Indeed, @Carpetsmoker . After all, the other option would be write a function for every indicator, not to mention add a function for every new indicator, and alter a function for every changed indicator. It won't cost just performance, but money (work time). None the less, maybe there's a diferent approach solution I overlook.